# Is there is a object to get the default date and time in java?

Tags: java, datetime

I need to get a default value of date and time, if a pass a parameter in a function I must get the following values:

```
public static main void (String [] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(getTimeRange("2019-12-02 10:20:20"));
}

public static String getTimeRange(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    Calendar selecteddate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    
    selecteddate.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));

    String startime = selecteddate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
        + selecteddate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + selecteddate.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return "Start Time: " + startime;
}
```

Comment: What makes January 1st at midnight a "default" value? And please don't use Date or Calendar, rather `LocalDateTime`

Comment: ok sure i will use LocalDateTime to pass the parameters.

Comment: any year if the user passes i need the beginning date and month

Comment: example if the use passes a value "2018-02"  then i need the second month first day as well following the time set to zero 00:00:00 because the use havent passed all the values

Comment: not sure if you are looking for date formatter with optionalend  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalEnd--

Comment: vmrvictor i m not looking for date formatter

Comment: what i am actually looking is that Date(String s)
Deprecated. 
As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s). visit this place https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Jon Skeet, Thank you very this approach is great but rather have a string template is there is any Date object which includes the following string within it "1970-01-01 00:00:00";

Comment: "i m not looking for date formatter" - you are if you're trying to parse a string as a `Date`, which sounds like what you actually want. You really, really shouldn't use the `Date(String)` constructor that was deprecated *over 20 years ago*.

Comment: thank you very much. now i know that there isn't possible way get the return values that i want.

Comment: you are right, that i dont need to use something which was used over 20 years ago

Comment: i got your message

Comment: "there isn't possible way get the returns values that I want"? then I didn't understand the question! Can you please edit and describe exactly what return values you want?

Comment: @Anver Could you please edit your question and fit in all the information you have kindly provided in comments? It’s a bit of hazzle to dig through all the comments to get the full picture of what you’re trying to obtain (which isn’t clear from the question as it stands). It would be really nice to have one coherent presentation of what you want on one place.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to produce a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017313/is-there-is-a-object-to-get-the-default-date-and-time-in-java/58018206?noredirect=1#comment102438562_58017313) by [vmrvictor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1511193/vmrvictor).

Keep in mind that a formatter can be used both for generating text as well as parsing.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(YEAR)
    .optionalStart()
      .appendLiteral('-')
      .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR)
      .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH)
        .optionalStart()
          .appendLiteral(' ')
          .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY)
        .optionalEnd()
      .optionalEnd()
    .optionalEnd()
    .parseDefaulting(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
    .parseDefaulting(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    .parseDefaulting(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .toFormatter();


private static LocalDateTime convert(String text) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
}
```

The returned [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object can be formatted at will, but I assumed that `2019-01-01 00:00:00` in the question indicates an object, compared to `"2019"` that represents a string.

Results for given data:

> ```
> "2019"  ->  2019-01-01 00:00:00
> "2019-02"  ->  2019-02-01 00:00:00
> "2019-06-02"  ->  2019-06-02 00:00:00
> "2019-07-2 11"  ->  2019-07-02 11:00:00
> ```

---

Here is a working test class using JUnit 5 Jupiter.

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class AppTest
{
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatterInput =
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder ()
                    .appendValue ( YEAR )
                    .optionalStart ()
                    .appendLiteral ( '-' )
                    .appendValue ( MONTH_OF_YEAR )
                    .optionalStart ()
                    .appendLiteral ( '-' )
                    .appendValue ( DAY_OF_MONTH )
                    .optionalStart ()
                    .appendLiteral ( ' ' )
                    .appendValue ( HOUR_OF_DAY )
                    .optionalEnd ()
                    .optionalEnd ()
                    .optionalEnd ()
                    .parseDefaulting ( MONTH_OF_YEAR , 1 )
                    .parseDefaulting ( DAY_OF_MONTH , 1 )
                    .parseDefaulting ( HOUR_OF_DAY , 0 )
                    .parseDefaulting ( MINUTE_OF_HOUR , 0 )
                    .parseDefaulting ( SECOND_OF_MINUTE , 0 )
                    .toFormatter ();

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );

    @Test
    public void testFormatter ( )
    {
        assertEquals ( "2019-01-01 00:00:00" , LocalDateTime.parse ( "2019" , AppTest.formatterInput ).format ( AppTest.formatterOutput ) );
        assertEquals ( "2019-02-01 00:00:00" , LocalDateTime.parse ( "2019-02" , AppTest.formatterInput ).format ( AppTest.formatterOutput ) );
        assertEquals ( "2019-06-02 00:00:00" , LocalDateTime.parse ( "2019-06-02" , AppTest.formatterInput ).format ( AppTest.formatterOutput ) );
        assertEquals ( "2019-07-02 11:00:00" , LocalDateTime.parse ( "2019-07-2 11" , AppTest.formatterInput ).format ( AppTest.formatterOutput ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious approach is just to have a "template" string that you effectively replace with "as much data as you've got":

```
public static String getTimeRange(String dateString) {
    // Note: you haven't told us what you want if the input is empty,
    // or longer than a full date/time
    String template = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";      
    return dateString + template.substring(dateString.length());
}
```

I believe this will satisfy all the sample input/output you gave.

Note that this does no parsing or other validation whatsoever - you may well want to parse the result into a `LocalDateTime` (as cricket_007 says, avoid `Date` and `Calendar` if possible) for validation. For example:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter parser =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);
public static LocalDateTime getTimeRange(String dateString) {
    // Note: you haven't told us what you want if the input is empty,
    // or longer than a full date/time
    String template = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";      
    String text = dateString + template.substring(dateString.length());
    return LocalDateTime.parse(text, parser);
}
```

If you *absolutely* have to use `java.util.Date`, which I'd strongly recommend against if at all possible, you can use an appropriate `SimpleDateFormat` which you already appear to know about as you're using one in the question.

Comment: thank you for the message, there want be any empty input.

Comment: I do not know if that's what Anver was looking for but It is simple and fine.

Comment: Jon Skeet, Thank you very this approach is great but rather have a string template is there is any Date object which includes the following string within it "1970-01-01 00:00:00";

Comment: @Anver: `Date` doesn't contain a string. It's a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, and that's all. If you want the result to be a `Date` instead of a `String`, just parse the result that my code is currently returning.

Comment: @Anver: But I'd strongly advise you to use `LocalDateTime` instead of `Date` if you possibly can. If you're being asked to use `Date` by your instructor, I'd suggest pushing back against that, because the `Date`/`Calendar` API is *horrible`, and you'd learn far more *useful* information using the modern java.time API.

Comment: further more, i need to return time reduce 10minits from the time that is passed. Therefore in that case i cant your method right

Comment: @Anver: I don't know what you mean by "reduce 10minits from the time that is passed" but that certainly wasn't part of your question. My answer does everything that you asked - if you have other requirements, you should ask them in a new question.

Comment: Rather than hardcoding `"1970-01-01 00:00:00"` you may generate it as `Instant.EPOCH.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` (using the same foratter as in the answer).

Comment: @OleV.V.: I don't know - I think it's far easier to know what the result is going to be with the hard-coded string. I do see your point, but in this case I think I'd personally prefer to just see the string.